# How can i specify range of vector?

Tags: cuda

i created two vector like that

```
thrust::host_vector<int> A(count);
thrust::generate(A.begin(),A.end(),rand);

thrust::host_vector<int> B(count);
thrust::generate(B.begin(),B.end(),rand);
```

count specifies the size of vector isn it ? What i want to do fill this vectors with 0 100 random numbers. How can i do that?

Comment: Do you mean generate the random numbers in the range [0, 100] ?

Comment: Although I have not worked with thrust, the documentation, which you should read, pointed me to the answer I posted. Your lack of effort may receive some downvotes. Anyway, I considered the question of interest for others

Answer (score 1):

The count paramenter in the `host_vector` constructor is the size of the vector. See [`host_vector`](http://docs.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/classthrust_1_1host__vector.html) documentation.

According with the [`generate`](http://docs.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/group__transformations.html#gaa6d990b511b9a2d92599d35bd58e7e9f) thrust documentation

> `generate`assigns the result of invoking `gen`, a function object that takes no arguments, to each element in the range [first,last).

So, create your randon function without arguments

```
int rand_from_0_to_100_gen(void)
{
     return rand() % 100;
}
```

And use it in the `thrust::generate` function

```
thrust::generate(A.begin(),A.end(),rand_from_0_to_100_gen);
```